# Get related items in keystone

Tags: node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

Working on a project in KeystoneJS and I'm having trouble figuring out the mongoose relationship bit.

According to the keystone docs, let's say we have the following models: `User` and `Post`. Now a post has a relationship to a user, so I'll write:

```
Post.add({
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' }
});
```

and then:

```
User.relationship({ path: 'posts', ref: 'Post', refPath: 'author' });
```

Now, I want to be able to see all posts related to that User without having to query for *both* a User *and* Posts. For example, if I queried for a user object I would like to be able to do `user.posts` and have access to those related posts. Can you do this with mongoose/keystone?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, keystone's [List Relationship](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationship-definitions) has nothing to do with mongoose and querying. Instead, it is used by keystone's admin UI to build out the relationship queries before rendering them in the view. This said I would forget `User.relationship(...);` solving your problem, although you want it for what I just mentioned.

The following should work fine based on your schema, but only populates the relationship on the `one` side:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
keystone.list('Post').model.findOne().populate('author', function (err, doc) {
  console.log(doc.author.name); // Joe
  console.log(doc.populated('author'));  // '1234af9876b024c680d111a1' -> _id
});
```

You could also try this the other way, however...

```
keystone.list('User').model.findOne().populate('posts', function (err, doc) {
  doc.posts.forEach(function (post) {
    console.log(post);
  });
});
```

...mongoose expects that this definition is added to the [Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema). This relationship is added by including this line in your User list file:

```
User.schema.add({ posts: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Post', many: true } })
```

After reading the keystone docs, this seems to be logically equivalent the mongoose pure way, `User.schema.add({ posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }] });`. And now you are now maintaining the relationship on both lists. Instead, you may want to add a [method](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-plugins) to your keystone list.

```
User.schema.methods.posts = function(done){
  return keystone.list('Post').model.find()
    .where('author', this.id )
    .exec(done);
};
```

By adding a method to your User list, it saves you from persisting the array of `ObjectId`s relating the MongoDB document back to the Post documents. I know this requires a second query, but one of these two options look to be your best bet.

Comment: Seems KeystoneJS v5 has no `model.find()` methods, any update?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on their github https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1888, check it for context, but basically says to use the keystone populateRelated() method. I tested it and does work

```
// if you've got a single document you want to populate a relationship on, it's neater
Category.model.findOne().exec(function(err, category) {
  category.populateRelated('posts', function(err) {
    // posts is populated
  });
});
```

I'm aware the question is old but this has to be out there for further reference